# Custom SF Symbols not visible in iOS 17 Beta

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, sf-symbols

We use a lot of custom SFSymbols in our app. We found a bug in iOS 17 that images has wrong appearance. Sometimes there are shown only parts of their outline, some symbols are totally filled by system (blue) tint color, so they ignore the default color of resource and also ignoring .tintColor parameter.

But when we use default Apple SF Symbols they work correctly.

[image: Screenshots from iOS 17 an iOS 16.5]

Everything works correctly in versions earlier iOS 17 so we want to know is it a bug or we do something wrong?

Example of usage SF in our workspace:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "*****_critical",
in: Bundle.main,
compatibleWith: nil)?.applyingSymbolConfiguration(UIImage.SymbolConfiguration.preferringMulticolor())
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.tintColor = myColor
```

[image: How visible my custom SF Symbols in Mac OS (13.4) SF Symbols App]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not Actually.** Fixed on last iOS 17 Beta